# Sceneform position node bottom screen

Tags: arcore, sceneform

What is the vector3 for displaying something at the bottom middle of the screen like a compass?
I found this: "Pose.makeTranslation(0, -0.07f, -0.2f);" but that doesnt work in with sceneform.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position something at the bottom of the screen, like a UI control that is not part of the scene, just add it like every standard Android UI element as an Android view that is above your ArFragment or our ArSceneView.

Answer (score 1):

Use this It worked in my app:

```
Anchor anchor = hitResult.getTrackable().createAnchor(hitResult.getHitPose().compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0,0.5f,0)));
```